# fsolve. Can we let Python decide the best initial guess?

Tags: python, numpy

Below is an example of solving nonlinear equation using fsolve. The answer can be found if appropriate initial guess is used. But, is there anyway, we write a code that let Python decide the best initial guess?

a+b = 3

(b/a)**b = 4

Any insight will be appreciated.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

sol = fsolve(lambda b: b*np.log(b/(3-b))-np.log(4), 1)[0]
print(sol)
```

Comment: So you're not actually looking for an efficient solution, but more for *any* solution? If you don't have a solution, everything that does is more efficient.

Comment: FYI: `fsolve` works if you give it a better initial guess, e.g. `sol = fsolve(lambda b: b*np.log(b/(3-b))-np.log(4), 1.4)[0]`

Comment: @ Weckesser, Thank you for your comment. Yes, a better initial guess would solve the error. But, how do we find an appropriate initial guess at the very beginning? I can try different numbers until I don't see error, but this is not what I'm looking for. Is there anyway, Python find the appropriate initial guess?

Comment: Finding a better guess may be more of a math (theory) issue than a programming one.

Comment: If there were a suitably generic way of identifying a useful initial guess, wouldn’t you expect `fsolve` to apply it rather than expecting a guess?